# Should be simple...MacOS Click+Drag on Desktop...how to change drag select box colours

Tags: colors, desktop, cursor

Hope you can assist with a small query.

Does anyone know how to adjust the colours from the default greys, of the drag select box on MacOS Desktop?

See image....
[Drag select box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZ2hk.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as far as i know, you can't. Maybe a [mySIMBL](https://github.com/w0lfschild/mySIMBL/releases) plugin might do the trick.

More info on customisation: https://www.maketecheasier.com/mysimbl-macos-customization/